# Deploy Flask app on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pythonanywhere

I have working simple blog. Code here - https://github.com/4doge/askMe

I already have account on pythonanywhere and Flask app. What i need now?

Specifically, what steps should I follow to get the code off github, onto pythonanywhere, and then make the blog site live on the Internet using pythonanywhere's service?

Comment: First try your self and say what problem you are getting

Answer (score 6):

I think these would be the next steps to deploy the app:

1. open a console: go to [pythonanywhere.com](https://pythonanywhere.com), click on `Consoles` and then on `Bash`
2. clone your app

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:4doge/askMe.git
   ```
3. You go to pythonanywhere.com and click on `Web`
4. click on add a new web app. (delete the old one if you have a free plan and do not need the old one)
5. click through and in the last dialog step you can choose the path to your `run.py`

Now the app should be running. You can restart it and browse it.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: just a quick note to say that `git` is already installed on our system so you don't need to do step 2.  (It actually wouldn't work, there's no `sudo` or `apt-get` access, but we make sure that all of the normal dev tools are preinstalled so there's normally no need to use either of them anyway.)